# Put generated ImageView in xml ImageView

Tags: android, view, imageview

I have a layout `activity_main` that (among other things) shows `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_button" />
```

I've created a class that extends`ImageView` and shows animated gif:

```
public class AnimatedGif extends ImageView
{
    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart = 0;

    public AnimatedGif(Context context, InputStream stream)
    {
        super(context);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(stream);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0)
        {
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        final int realTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(realTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

In the main activity I use the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
.
.
.
InputStream stream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.searching_gif);
AnimatedGif gifImageView = new AnimatedGif(this, stream);
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
```

How can I make that `im` will show `gifImageView`??

Comment: Use that custom ImageView instead in XML like this: `<com.packagename.AnimatedGif  android:id="@+id/profileImageView"` and in java class instead of `ImageView image;` use `AnimatedGif   image;`

Comment: Keep everything else the same. Just change `<ImageView`  to `<com.packagename.AnimatedGif`

Comment: @Tushar it crashes on setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Did you replace **com.packagename** with your package name?

Comment: @Tushar Yes. It was because I didn't have the constructor: public AnimatedGif(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: @Tushar Nope..... it draws nothing :(

Comment: Must the custom class logic. You basically want to show a gif file, right? There is a lib for that or you can use WebView and pass the url to it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Nope it also draws nothing.... i'll look more into it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK his custom class AnimatedGif's code   is not working, adding view is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. At least the way you though about it. You need some minimal changes, to load your `AnimatedGif` directly into the layout. The first is a constructor that takes as parameter the `Context` and the `AttributeSet`:

```
public AnimatedGif(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

}
```

this way you can add it directly as item of the xml, specifying the full qualified package to the class

```
<com.package.AnimatedGif
     android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_button" />
```

now you probably want to have a custom attribute to specify the gif you want to load. So you could declare in your attr.xml file

```
<declare-styleable name="AnimatedGif">
    <attr name="gifres" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and inside the constructor you can load it like

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AnimatedGif);
int value = a.getInt(R.styleable.AnimatedGif_gifres, 0)); 
stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(value);
a.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I make that im will show gifImageView??

Because `activity_main.xml` is layout for Activity in which want to add custom `ImageView` using code:

**1.**  Use `LinearLayout` in  `activity_main.xml` as root Layout and set `orientation` to `vertical`

**2.** Assign id to root Layout of `activity_main.xml` like:

```
     android:id="@+id/main_layout"
```

**3.** Get root layout in `onCreate` method:

```
     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
```

**4.** Now add `gifImageView` view object to linearLayout:

```
     linearLayout.addView(gifImageView);
```